# Where to store values calculated from props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

What is the best place to store the result of an expensive calculation from the React props which I use in `render()` but do not want to execute at each `render()` ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const result = this.doExpensiveCalculation(props)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // if nextProps differ from props
    const result = this.doExpensiveCalculation(nextProps)
}

doExpensiveCalculation(props) {
   // Some expensive stuff 
}

render(){
    // Use doExpensiveCalculation(this.props) here
}
```

The options are `this` and `state` but both I see rather unsatisfying. Is there a ready solution which uses memoisation?

On the other hand, should I worry about optimizing this ? I read that React can rerender component even if the props have not changed but does this happen often ?

Comment: You should save `result` in state. And if possible `doExpensiveCalculation` should be done in async way. If you are using something like redux and redux-saga, this should be straightforward to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the re-rendering in the lifecycle method of `shouldComponentUpdate`. Default value is always `return true`. By returning false there React will not re-render the component.

See the [docs for more](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Besides that, React only updates if a state change occurs since props are read-only.

Your options are to store it as you suggested or have a class with a static field to keep it there.

Comment: This solution does not solve the case that some data change should update the component but should not recalcuate the value. The value has to be saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is perform the expensive calculation whenever you get new props, instead of on every render, you probably want [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> `componentWillReceiveProps()` is invoked before a mounted component receives new props.

As far as where to store them, you can either store them in state, or as a property directly on the component instance. Either will work just as well.

You want to make sure compare values though, to avoid unnecessarily recomputing.

For example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.someValue !== this.props.someValue) {
        this.someResult = this.performExpensiveCalculation(nextProps.someValue);
    }
}
```